# How do I find what's using an indirectly linked library?

Tags: linked-data

Something in the file I'm working on is linked from another file, and it's getting it's materials from a third file. I've moved everything and I'm renaming the paths to fix broken libraries. I can't rename that one, because it's an indirectly linked library. However, I can't figure out what it is that it's linked to, because I don't know what linked item is in turn linking to it. There's a bunch of them, it would take a while to poke around and find it. Is there a way I can track it down?